# Unity System and Newtonsoft libraries does not work when built for android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, unity-game-engine, apk

I am new at Unity but I have some experience at Asp.Net programming. I need to develop a application which need to connect an API and get,post,delete some datas from that API. In order to achieve that, I am using these libraries below:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

When I run the application, there is no any error, warning etc. on my computer (I am using Unity 2020.3.24f1). It works exactly how I want. But when I build it for android platform (apk) and install it to my android phone, my codes which use these libraries does not work on the phone. I can not see any error on the phone screen just does not work. I hope I could explain.

Comment: Why not use the json utility that comes with Unity?

Comment: i assume you are missing some exception handling so you don't catch errors properly. You presumably get a PlattformNotSupported exception. You need to use libraries that support your deployment targets and NewtonSoft does not out of the box. Something like this https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "Unity System" .. you are using the general `c#` [`System`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system) and [`System.Net.Http`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http) namespaces! And in general from [`System.Net`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net)

> Classes in the System.Net namespace can be used to develop Windows Store apps or desktop apps.

so this doesn't exist on `Android`.

---

You should rather use Unity's [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html), [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) and [`UnityWebRequest.Delete`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Delete.html) accordingly.

---

For JSON either stick to the built-in [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) if possible or make sure to use the "semi-built-in" [**package** Newtonsoft JSON](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) you can install via the [Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui@2.0/manual/index.html) (if it is not the case anyway for newer versions by default).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps.